# Can we use "depot" as an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, orthography, parts-of-speech, is-it-a-word, attributive-nouns

Can we use *depot* in this form: *depotted books* or *depot books*?
(I’m not sure about the past participle of this word.)

Or should it be used only as a “place” where books are supposed to be
stored, a *depot of books*?

Comment: There are examples of 'the depot workers' (compare 'the shopworkers') on the internet. Nouns that cannot be used attributively are rare, but that does not mean that all pairings are idiomatic.

Comment: I think you're using *depot* as a verb ("place in the depot") whose past participle *depot'd* might be used an adjective. However, neither OED, Lexico, MW, Cambridge, Macmillan nor Collins license *depot* as a verb. Collins does [explicitly list it as an adjective](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/depot), but with a very specialised meaning.

Comment: If so, would you please let me know which one of these forms is acceptable? "depot books" or "depotted books"? (My Grammarly has already highlighted "depotted")

"Nouns that cannot be used attributively are rare" 
Thank you, good point. (How may I find those rare nouns?)

Comment: 'Books at/from the depot' or 'depot's books'. // 'How may I find those rare nouns?' is off-topic, frivolous, and probably by the time you've found 100 50 of them will have found their way into accepted pairings. Look up a rare noun (eg 'agelast', 'meldrop') and then Google "an agelast" etc to see if there are any attributive-usage examples.

Comment: depot road, depot sales, ex-depot price...

Comment: @RamPillai What’s your point? Those are not adjectives.

Comment: @tchrist, Acc to conventional grammar they are, because in each set the former describes the latter.

Comment: @RamPillai That is necessary but not sufficient. If *depot* can here be modified by an adverb but not by an adjective, then it is probably not a noun. If it can be modified by an adjective but not by an intensifier, it is probably a noun. Other syntactic tests exist. If by "traditional grammar" you mean silly old Donatus’s parts of speech, then that's many centuries out of date and of no use to us whatsoever. If you mean a grammar that does not recognize determiners and intensifiers and articles and such, it is again of no use to us in this century nor in the last either for that matter.

Comment: @RamPillai  This is not a matter of "conventional grammar". It is a matter of any sort of grammar taught to children older than seven years of age. Compound nouns made up of only nouns do not have their parts changed into adjectives. See *snow shoes, dog food, house boat, running pants, bumper cars, pencil sharpener, ballot box, barn door, pickle jar,* and a million others. None of those are modifiable by *very*; they have no adjectives, only nouns.

Comment: @tchrist, I of course go by your second comment, just above. As for your first comment, yes, you understood it correctly.  I used the word 'conventional grammar' not unknowingly.

Comment: And, @tchrist, it's your choice to label the conventional grammar as silly or or 'of no use'.  Don't you think that the linguistic level where we currently are has evolved from there? Our next gen will rewrite this too.   ;) (...not being philosophical).

Comment: Ignoring the adjective bit, the verbing bit makes an interesting question. *Depot* has long been verbed in the logistics business, meaning to consign or relegate to a depot.  In casual notes, I adopted depo'ed as the spelling, but I never saw the word in a formal document. So I score it as a relatively common and longstanding usage that has no established written use at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that *depot* rhymes not with *Camelot* nor with *pipit*, but with *sheepo*. It ends with a vowel, not a consonant, so attempting to apply verbal inflections to the noun would result in spellings that would confuse people.

Only if you had first *potted* your book could you then consider ***de**potting* it. And while *pot* as a verb can have other meanings, most people would think of plants when potting things. A *depotted* plant would therefore be an unpotted plant, an uprooted one. I don’t know how you uproot books, though, so I rather doubt your readers would, either.

To answer your question’s title in the most direct way possible, absolutely not: *depot* is never an adjective. You’ll never have a very depot book, and one book cannot be any more depot than another can be. Therefore you may not use *depot* as an adjective.

You can, however, use *depot* as a noun. One sense given by the OED is:

> Applied to a portion of a regiment which remains at home when the rest are on foreign service.

They observe that this sense lends itself to the formation of compound nouns.

Citations include:

- **1853**   J. H. Stocqueler *Mil. Encycl*. 82/2 
    Regiments embarking for India usually leave one company at home, for the purpose of recruiting, which is called the depôt company.
- 1**8**81   *Chicago Times* 16 Apr. 
    The company is constructing a depot building..at Leaf River.
- **1884**   C. R. Markham in *Pall Mall Gaz*. 20 Aug. 1/2  
   The party should never have been left without a depot ship wintering within accessible distance.

Originally a loanword from the French word *dépôt* (Old French *depost*, which it in turn received from the Latin *dēpositum*), this word is related to the English noun *deposit* of the same origin. It is used in various senses, but it is never used as an adjective, only as a noun as shown in all three citations provided above.

Order matters here. A *book depot* is a depot **for** books.  A *depot book* is a book **about** depots, or maybe a book **from** a depot. You will note that no adjectives have been used in the construction of any of these compounds, only nouns alone.

---

Because of discussion in comments, there’s something that apparently needs to be cleared up.

Attributive noun use does not equate to “using a noun as an adjective”. That’s a facile, deceptive description that quickly falls apart under trivial syntactic tests:

1. Notice how unlike the case with facile, deceptive descriptions, you can’t have a ❌ depot, deceptive book. This is because *facile* is an adjective but *depot* is  a noun.
2. Just how ❌ depot a book is this depot book you have? It isn’t, because *depot* is never an adjective. A book can never be ❌  depot.
3. The same reason explains why a pretty depot book is not a book that is ❌ pretty depot. It’s a pretty book that is **at** or **from** a depot. Contrast this with a pretty big book, which is a book that’s pretty big, and you will quickly see the difference between an attributive noun and an attributive adjective because *big* is an adjective but *depot* is not.

I hope this clearly illustrates why we **must** say that *depot* is still functioning as a noun here, not as an adjective. Just because both nouns and adjectives can be used attributively does not mean that doing so changes the one into the other. It does not. They remain separate things. To allege otherwise mistakes parts of speech with grammatical roles. The modifier role is not a part of speech; it is a syntactic function applicable to numerous sorts of syntactic constituents.

Comment: You helped me a lot. I appreciate it. So, how do we call items stored in a depot? depot stuff? depot items? how may I use depot in this manner?

Comment: @tchrist -  "depot is never an adjective" I have never needed to have a [depot](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/depot) injection, but I have heard of people who have - **depot adjective** "(of a drug or drug dose) designed for gradual release from the site of an injection so as to act over a long period" - used for e.g. antipsychotic or contraceptive purposes

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Is that only limited to drugs? in "depot book" meaning a book from a depot, what's the role of "depot" here?

Comment: In the British Army, a regiment can be divided into numbered 'battalions', e.g. the 1st Battalion, Coldstream Guards, and these can be assigned to larger formations, such as brigades. Until the early 20th century each regiment would have a 'depot battalion' which was assigned to the regimental headquarters and handled recruitment, administration, etc. Railways have depots where carriages, locomotives, freight wagons, etc, are stored and repaired, and each might have shunting engines called 'depot shunters', as well as a person holding the title of 'depot superintendent', 'depot manager', etc.

Comment: @Learner The problem is that Collins denies the existence of attributive nouns.  They pretend that *bear* is an adjective in compounds like *bear market* and *bear meat*, that *stock* is an adjective as in *stock market* *stock boy*, and that *house* is an adjective as in *house wine* and *house window*.  This is pure nonsense, and the OED will not have it, calling all three of those cases of **nouns used attributively, *not* adjectives**. Listen to the stress: if the first word in those compounds is stressed, it’s a noun, but if unstressed, an adjective.

Comment: @tchrist. The question title is "Can we **use** “depot” **as an adjective**?" - the answer, Collins or not, is clearly "Yes". An attributive noun functions as an adjective.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey No, sir. Attributive noun use does not equate to “using a noun as an adjective”. That’s a facile, deceptive description that quickly falls apart under trivial syntactic tests. Notice that you can’t have a ❌ depot, deceptive book. How ❌ depot a book is this depot book you have? It isn’t, because *depot* is never an adjective, which is why a pretty depot book is not a book  that is ❌ pretty depot. It’s a pretty book that is at or from a depot. I hope this clearly illustrates to you why we must say that *depot* is still functioning as a noun here, not as an adjective.